# Cannot convert undefined or null to object in jasmine it function

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

I have test like this:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom;
var document = jsdom('<html></html>', {});
var window = document.defaultView;
global.jQuery = global.$ = require('jquery')(window);

$.platform = {};
require('../runtime/platform/js/modules/platform.upload.js');
var self = $.platform.upload;

describe('platform.upload.js', function() {
    console.log('<<<<<<<<<' + Object.keys($.platform.upload));

    it('should work', function() {
        console.log('<<<<<<<<<' + Object.keys($.platform.upload));
        self.sendFiles([], 'file', $('<form></form>'));
    });
});
```

platform.upload.js defined $.patform.upload object and when I try to access Object.keys inside `it` function I've got error "Cannot convert undefined or null to object", `Object.keys` inside `describe` works fine. Why I've got this error and how to fix this? I cound just use `self` but sendFiles function also need to access `$.platform.upload` and I've got different error "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" when I try to access `$.platform.upload.name`.

I'm using jasmine-node from grunt using grunt-jasmine-nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue with this code:

```
describe('platform.upload.js', function() {
    var plaform = $.platform;
    describe('sendFiles', function() {
        it('should upload file', function() {
            $.platform = plaform;
            self.sendFiles([], 'file', $('<form></form>'));
        });
    });
});
```